# Spring WS(SOAP) in Java 17

Tags: java, spring-ws

Can I use Spring WS module in Java 17 or Spring WS does not support Java 17 yet?

I need realize how can I build project SOAP service use Spring WS in Java 17

Answer (score -1):

Spring WS supports Java 8 and above, so it should work with Java 17. You can build a SOAP service project using Spring WS in Java 17.